# Application cannot load Microsoft.SqlServer.Types Version 13

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2016

I am having a problem that many people have had before but none of the existing answers seem to work for me.

When I deploy my ASP.NET project I get an error in the event log saying

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

To try to rectify this I installed the Nuget package:

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

This didn't work and I get the same error.  So then I followed the readme and used `Loader.cs` to load the files. Again, same problem. What is happening and why don't the usual solutions fix it?

One thing I did note is that my `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` is version 11 not 13? If it makes any difference our database is SqlServer 2016 and our machine is running Windows Server 2008

Comment: Chris  where you able to resolve this issue? im having similar issues and done all the standard ways of trying to fix it.

Comment: @InitLipton Yes I did actually, I've just added an answer for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved this was to to set the `SqlServerTypesAssemblyName` in my app.  I currently set it in my `EntityContext` constructor [that inherits off `DbContext`] to ensure its always set

```
SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName 
            = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";
```

Note your version may want to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are reference the correct version of assembly.

If not add manually.

[image: Add manually]

Once the nuget package is installed you can ensure that the dll reference property is set to 'copy local = true'

Comment: Thanks but the nuget package doesnt seem to contain v13, any ideas where to get it?

Comment: @KT.Thor  I have the "Copy Local" = True and the reference is to Version 13 but Visual Studio still says it wants to use Version 10.